# GCC Fails to Generate Object Files When Compiling

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Recently I have noticed that GCC does not generate object (*.o) files when compiling with '-c'. It does not issue any errors or warnings. I have run it with '-verbose' but it shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Running under Windows:

```
gcc -Wall -c source_file.c
```

I have also tried compiling with '-verbose' to display detailed information

```
gcc -Wall -verbose -c source_file.c
```

It should produce 'source_file.o' but it doesn't. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It working for me. try `gcc -c  source_file.c -o source_file.o` then `gcc source_file.o -o executable`

Comment: @Jayesh It still does not work...

Comment: There's no output at all?

Comment: Which version of gcc? (use gcc -dumpversion) Was gcc working for you until something changed (like an upgrade), or have you never had a working gcc?

Comment: @lornix `-c` tells gcc to just compile, not to create an executabe. Specifying option `-c` the result of compiling a `.c` file per default is a correspondig `.o` file.

Comment: @alk, yup, you're right!  My apologies.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Reinstalling GCC (mingw) fixed the problem. It is possible the problem came about because I tried to install the 64-bit version of GCC (Mingw-w64) to top of the 32-bit version...